# need help to draw bitmaps for video streaming

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to play video, where I get frames as bitmaps from the native code and I want to display the video on the screen. I do not understand how to display them, as there are view, surface, animation and graphics and I have no idea, which one to use from these. I am very beginner to android. Please help me choosing and let me know if there are any samples.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve it myself. Answer is as follows

**C Code :**

in renderbitmap function

```
AndroidBitmapInfo  info;
void*              pixels;
int                ret;

if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info)) < 0) {
return;
}

if (info.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565) {
return;
}

if ((ret =AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels)) < 0) {
}

memcpy(pixels, pictureRGB, 480*320);

AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
```

**Java Code**

```
 Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 320, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
 renderbitmap(mBitmap, 0);
 canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so displaying bitmaps can be done using imageviews that can be embedded in your layout.

```
ImageView bmImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
bmImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // insert bitmap that you get from video
```

Did i understand you correctly?)

Comment: NO. This when you have an image from resource. What if you have read the pixel information and want to display bitmaps to display a video frame?